# How to use datatable for SSRS Report in SSRS Class Library?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Hi I created a simple Class in SSRS solution.

```
Public Class Class1

    Dim table As DataTable = GetTable()
    Function GetTable() As DataTable
        ' Create new DataTable instance.
        Dim table As New DataTable

        ' Create four typed columns in the DataTable.
        table.Columns.Add("Dosage", GetType(Integer))
        table.Columns.Add("Drug", GetType(String))
        table.Columns.Add("Patient", GetType(String))
        table.Columns.Add("Date", GetType(DateTime))

        ' Add five rows with those columns filled in the DataTable.
        table.Rows.Add(25, "Indocin", "David", DateTime.Now)
        table.Rows.Add(50, "Enebrel", "Sam", DateTime.Now)
        table.Rows.Add(10, "Hydralazine", "Christoff", DateTime.Now)
        table.Rows.Add(21, "Combivent", "Janet", DateTime.Now)
        table.Rows.Add(100, "Dilantin", "Melanie", DateTime.Now)
        Return table
    End Function
End Class
```

can I use this table in my report?

Thank you

ps: I don't want to use report viewer in VB.net project, because I really want to use NATIVE SSRS, so I can design report parameter the regular way.